# How do I negate login.aspx in the web.config with Wordpress

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, iis, url-rewrite-module

We have recently created a Wordpress site which will be hosted on a Windows 2012 Server. The server is currently serving compiled code of which one of the URL's it uses is `login.aspx`.

When we add the Wordpress site and enable permalinks, we get the default Wordpress page instead of `login.aspx`.

We have unsurprisingly narrowed it down to the `web.config` rewrite rule.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*"/>
            <conditions>                 
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I'm sure we have to negate the `login.aspx` page some how but I'm not sure how to do it. This has to work as a single site for now.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was add in the following:

```
<add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="*.aspx" />
```